# AspNet.Identity throws InvalidOperationException when used with SimpleInjector

Tags: c#, asp.net, inversion-of-control, asp.net-identity, simple-injector

I have a simple ASP.NET vNext project, with ASP Identity and SimpleInjector configured (according to http://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/aspnetintegration.html).

Registration works fine, however when I try to log in I get an error:

`InvalidOperationException: No authentication handler is configured to handle the scheme: Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Application`

If I comment out the lines for SimpleInjector everything works just fine, which seems kind of weird. Google didn't help me either :/

This is my Startup class.

```
public class Startup
{
    //SimpleInjector IOC container
    private readonly Container _container = new Container();

    private IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);

        builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddEntityFramework()
                .AddSqlServer()
                .AddDbContext<MyIdentityDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"]));

        services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>(options =>
        {
            //TODO 
            options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
            options.Password.RequiredLength = 1;
            options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
            options.Password.RequireNonLetterOrDigit = false;
            options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
        }).AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyIdentityDbContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddMvc();

        services.AddInstance<IControllerActivator>(new SimpleInjectorControllerActivator(_container));
        services.AddInstance<IViewComponentInvokerFactory>(new SimpleInjectorViewComponentInvokerFactory(_container));
        //
        // Work around for a Identity Framework bug inside the SignInManager<T> class.
        services.Add(ServiceDescriptor.Instance<IHttpContextAccessor>(new NeverNullHttpContextAccessor()));
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        ConfigureSimpleInjector(app);

        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseIISPlatformHandler(options => options.AuthenticationDescriptions.Clear());
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseIdentity();

        app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
    }

    private void ConfigureSimpleInjector(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        _container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new AspNetRequestLifestyle();

        app.UseSimpleInjectorAspNetRequestScoping(_container);

        //register all of the services
        RegisterServices(app);

        _container.RegisterAspNetControllers(app);
        _container.RegisterAspNetViewComponents(app);
        _container.Verify();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Register all of the required services for IoC
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="app"></param>
    private void RegisterServices(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        //DB
        RegisterDbServices(app);

        //IDENTITY
        _container.CrossWire<UserManager<User>>(app);
        _container.CrossWire<SignInManager<User>>(app);

        //register services
        _container.CrossWire<ILoggerFactory>(app);
    }

    private void RegisterDbServices(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        _container.RegisterSingleton<IDocumentStore>(() =>
        {
            var store = new DocumentStore
            {
                Url = Configuration["Data:RavenDB:URL"]
            };
            store.Initialize();

            return store;
        });
        _container.Register(() =>
        {
            var session = _container.GetInstance<IDocumentStore>().OpenAsyncSession();
            session.Advanced.UseOptimisticConcurrency = true;
            return session;
        }, Lifestyle.Scoped);
    }

    // Entry point for the application.
    public static void Main(string[] args) => WebApplication.Run<Startup>(args);

    /// <summary>
    /// Workaround for Identity bug: http://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/aspnetintegration.html
    /// </summary>
    private sealed class NeverNullHttpContextAccessor : IHttpContextAccessor
    {
        private readonly AsyncLocal<HttpContext> _context = new AsyncLocal<HttpContext>();

        public HttpContext HttpContext
        {
            get { return _context.Value ?? new DefaultHttpContext(); }
            set { _context.Value = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

The stacktrace:

```
 System.InvalidOperationException: No authentication handler is configured to handle the scheme: Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Application
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Authentication.Internal.DefaultAuthenticationManager.d__13.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.SignInManager`1.d__27.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.SignInManager`1.d__43.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.SignInManager`1.d__30.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.SignInManager`1.d__31.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Movies.Web.Controllers.AccountController.d__6.MoveNext() in C:\Users\mojol\Documents\C#\Web\Movies\src\Movies.Web\Controllers\AccountController.cs:line 68
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActionExecutor.d__8`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActionInvoker.d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Controllers.FilterActionInvoker.d__53.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Controllers.FilterActionInvoker.d__44.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Infrastructure.MvcRouteHandler.d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Routing.Template.TemplateRoute.d__27.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Routing.RouteCollection.d__9.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Builder.RouterMiddleware.d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler.IISPlatformHandlerMiddleware.d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity.MigrationsEndPointMiddleware.d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.d__7.MoveNext()
```

Comment: Please can you show all the exception details?

Comment: "If I comment out the lines for SimpleInjector everything works just fine". Which lines are you commenting out? The stack trace contains no sign of Simple Injector. I'm unsure how this is related to Simple Injector.

Comment: `ConfigureSimpleInjector(app);`

 in the Configure method and 

`services.AddInstance<IControllerActivator>(new SimpleInjectorControllerActivator(_container));
services.AddInstance<IViewComponentInvokerFactory>(new SimpleInjectorViewComponentInvokerFactory(_container));`

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. It's easy to reproduce - create new ASP.NET project from asp.net 5 template(rc1) with Individual User Account (Identity 3 rc1). And apply simpleinject beta template from wiki.(link above).
Here is my result http://pastebin.com/phJkBDCY
Have the same stack trace

Comment: Did you have any luck in solving this @Domas?? I've been banging my head against the wall now for several hours with no luck.